# Was bedeutet das Wort "um" in Phrasen wie "um 5% gestiegen", "um 10C gestiegen" und "um XYZ --"?

Tags: phrase, etymology

Ich spekuliere, dass "um XYZ gestiegen" aus der Phrase "um XYZ herum gestiegen" entstanden ist, d.h. "ungefähr XYZ gestiegen" bedeutet und damit nicht genau ist.

Meine Lehrerin sagt allerdings, dass diese Aussage sehr präzise ist, ebenso wie "um 1°C gestiegen" und "um 30% gestiegen". Ich dagegen denke, es ist anders.

Meiner Auffassung nach kann ich die Wortkombination "um XYZ gestiegen" auch nicht mit präzisen Zahlen wie 44.33333333...% verwenden, weil sie von sich aus der Ungenauigkeit "um ... herum" hineinbringt und so mit der Präzision der Zahl nicht vereinbar ist. Ich weiß natürlich nicht, ob meine Idee richtig ist - ich spekuliere hier lediglich.

Würde ich mit "um XYZ" eine präzise Aussage machen, oder sollte ich eine andere Phrase wählen? Hat die Bedeutung der Phrase sich geändert?

Comment: I edited your question quite heavily. Please don't feel offended and feel free to do a rollback if you disagree with my edit.

Comment: @Jan: danke! Ja, es ist jetzt viel besser aber ohne meine "um...herum" Prämisse. Es ist ganz wichtig so ich habe es neumal da.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"Um" hat hier nicht die Bedeutung von "etwa" (also einer Ungenauigkeit, wie in "um 10° *herum*", im Englischen "about 10°"), sondern zeigt eine *relative Veränderung* eines Wertes an (im Englischen "by 10°").

Der Satz

> Die Temperatur ist in der letzten Stunde um 10° gestiegen.

sagt somit nicht aus, dass es *ungefähr* 10° waren. Er sagt aus, dass die Temperatur vor einer Stunde 10° niedriger war als jetzt. Den Grad der Genauigkeit kann man durch das Einfügen von Worten wie "ungefähr" oder "genau" direkt vor dem genannten Wert ausdrücken.

Anders sieht es aus, wenn es in der Aussage nicht um eine Wert*veränderung* geht, sondern nur um eine Aussage über einen aktuellen Wert:

> Die Temperatur beträgt im Moment um 10 °C.

Hier wird ausgedrückt, dass der Wert ungefähr 10 °C beträgt.

---

[Im Österreichischen](http://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_3/f11a/) wird "um" auch für (genaue!) Preisangaben verwendet, was Deutsche regelmäßig verunsichert:

> Österreichisch: Die DVD gibt's bei meinem Händler um 10 €.
>
> (Deutsche Entsprechung: Die DVD gibt's bei meinem Händler *für* 10 €.)

Comment: Ich wußte nicht dass "um 10€" *nur* in Österreich für genaue Preisangaben verwendet wird!

Comment: @JoachimSauer: also für die Schweiz und Bayern will ich mich jetzt nicht verbürgen, aber ich kenn's eigentlich nur aus Österreich. Edit: Habe einen Link hinzugefügt.

Comment: Bayern ist bei vielen "nur in Österreich"-Konstrukten ja ohnehin implizit inkludiert ;-)

Comment: @JoachimSauer :-D

Comment: ja aber warum is es "um"? Hast es etwas mit "um...herum" zu tun? Was ist die Geschichte?

Comment: @hhh das Wort "um" hat einfach mehrere Bedeutungen. Eine ist "um <irgendetwas> herum" (das kann übrigens auch örtlich gemeint sein - "ich fahre um die Stadt herum"), eine andere ist eben eine Veränderung "um <irgendeinen Wert>". Einen direkten Zusammenhang kann ich Dir leider nicht herstellen. Es gibt aber einen recht ausführlichen [Wiktionary-Eintrag](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/um) dazu, falls Du Dich stärker in die Sache vertiefen willst :-)

Comment: Wenn übrigens tatsächlich nur ungefähre Wertangaben verwendet werden sollen, so ist ein passendes Konstrukt "um die". z.B. "die Preise sind um die 30% gestiegen"; "die Temperatur ist um die 10° gefallen", "diese DVD kostet um die 10€".

Comment: @down-voter: Bitte um Verbesserungsvorschlag!

Comment: @Jan: Betrifft: »*Die DVD gibt's bei meinem Händler **um** 10 €.*«: Du solltest vielleicht ergänzen, wie man diesen Satz in Deutschland formulieren sollte damit er dort verstanden wird. Mir fällt nämlich gerade keine Alternative zu »um« ein. - Danke! (p.S. Zwischen *10* und *€* fehlt ein Leerzeichen)

Comment: @nd01 Man würde "um die" nur sagen, nicht schreiben. Bei einem Differenzwert z.B. "die Preise sind um etwa 30% gestiegen" und bei einem Preis z.B. "die DVD kostet etwa/ca./ungefähr 10 Euro".

Answer (score 10):

Das **um** dient dazu eine Differenz auszudrücken. Im Gegensatz dazu benutzt man **auf,** um den absoluten Wert zu bezeichnen, der erreicht wird.

> Es ist von 5 °C um 10 °C auf 15 °C gestiegen.

Comment: Schön knapp. :)