# »Die DVD gibt's um 10 €.« in deutschem Deutsch

Tags: austrian, varieties

In einer Antwort zu einer [anderen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2547/was-bedeutet-das-wort-um-in-phrasen-wie-um-5-gestiegen-um-10c-gestiegen), bei der es um das Wort *um* ging, wurde unter anderem das geschrieben:

> Im Österreichischen wird "um" auch für (genaue!) Preisangaben verwendet, was Deutsche regelmäßig verunsichert:
>
> Die DVD gibt's bei meinem Händler um 10€.

Nun bin ich Österreicher und kann bestätigen, dass diese Formulierung korrektes österreichisches Deutsch ist, aber mir will nicht einfallen, welches Wort man im Ausland (also in Deutschland und der Schweiz) anstelle von *um* verwenden könnte.

Wie würde man den Satz »Die DVD gibt's um 10 €.« in korrektem deutschem Deutsch formulieren?

Comment: Die DVD gibt es für 10 EUR (zu kaufen / in jedem Laden / etc.)

Comment: Wenn ich (Dresden) `gibt es um 10 Euro` höre, würde ich erstmal denken, dass ich sie vielleicht auch schon für 8 Euro kaufen könnte. Oder das sie vielleicht sogar 12 Euro kostet. Sprich für mich klingt `um X Euro` wie `etwa für X Euro` oder `in der Drehe von X Euro`.

Comment: @blutorange: Für diesen Zwecken haben wir Österreicher die Wörter »ungefähr« und »circa« im Vokabular. »Die DVD gibt es um *ungefähr* 10 €« heißt, dass sie möglicherweise auch 8 oder 12 Euro kostet. »Die DVD gibt es um 10 €« heißt aber, dass sie genau 10 Euro kostet. »In der Drehe von« klingt für österreichische Ohren sehr nach Piefke. Das hört man nur vor Touristen und Immigranten aus Deutschland.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die in Österreich übliche Formulierung „die DVD gibt es *um* zehn Euro“ entspricht der in Deutschland vorherrschenden Formulierung „die DVD gibt es *für* zehn Euro.“

Zum Verbreitungsgebiet dieser Ausdrücke gibt es eine Karte im *[Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-3/f11a/):*

[image: Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache]

Comment: Interessant. Müsste ich den Satz »Die DVD gibt es für ...« ergänzen, käme mir nie in den Sinn da einen Preis einzusetzen. Ich würde dazu tendieren einen Namen einzusetzen, z.B. »Die DVD gibt es für **Maria**«, und würde mich gleichzeitig sehr darüber wundern dass diese DVD nur von Maria erworben werden kann.

Comment: Da ergibt sich eine Folgefrage: Wenn die DVD gratis wäre, würde man (zumindest in Österreich) sagen: »Die DVD gibt es **um**sonst«. Das Wort »umsonst« stammt vom dem Mittelhochdeutschen »umbe sus« ab (wörtlich: »um ein so«, wobei man das *sus/so* meist mit einer wegwerfenden Handbewegung begleitete, um anzudeuten, das damit »nichts« gemeint ist). Ich kann mir schwer vorstellen, dass man in Deutschland statt »das gibt es umsonst« »das gibt es **für**sonst« sagt. Daher glaube ich eher, dass in Deutschland irgendwann das »umbe« durch »für« ersetzt wurde, während das in Ö nicht geschah. Warum?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Würdest du im Satz "Ich gebe  dir 10€ *für* deine DVD" auch "um" verwenden?

Comment: @RomanReiner: Nein, denn »deine DVD« ist kein Geldbetrag, sondern das Handelsgut. Aber ich kann dich zum Subjekt machen und dann sagen: »Du gibst mir deine DVD *um* 10 €«. Die DVD ist das Handelsgut, die 10 Euro sind die Bezahlung dafür. Es ist ja nicht so, dass ich dir 10 Euro abkaufe und sie mit einer DVD bezahle, sondern du kaufst mir eine DVD ab und bezahlst mit 10 Euro.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Aber genau deswegen sagen wir Deutschen ja *für*. Egal ob Geld oder Handelsgut. Geld ist ja letztlich auch nur ein Tauschmittel.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast "fürsonst" sagt man meines Wissens tatsächlich nicht - "[für umme](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/umme)" kannst Du aber hin und wieder hören