# Wann wurde in Deutschland aus »um 10 Euro/Mark/Taler« »für 10 ...«?

Tags: etymology, varieties

In einer [anderen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20572/die-dvd-gibts-um-10-%E2%82%AC-in-deutschem-deutsch) wurde bereits geklärt, dass Preisangaben im Österreich und Deutschland unterschiedlich formuliert werden:

> Ö: Die DVD gibt es **um** 10 Euro.
>   D: Die DVD gibt es **für** 10 Euro.

Dennoch sagt man nicht nur in Österreich, sondern auch in Deutschland

> Ö+D: Die DVD gibt es **um**sonst.

wenn sie gratis ist.

Das moderne deutsche Wort »*um*« stammt vom mittelhochdeutschen »*umbe*« ab, und der Ursprung von »*umsonst*« ist »*umbe sus*«, wobei »*sus*« eigentlich »*so*« bedeutet, in diesem Kontext aber als »*nichts*« übersetzt werden muss.

kleiner Exkurs:
Laut Duden Herkunftswörterbuch bedeutet »*umbe sus*« wörtlich »*um (ein) so*«, wobei das Wort »*so*« meist von einer wegwerfenden Handbewegung begleitet worden sein soll, um anzudeuten, dass damit »*um nichts*« gemeint war.

Also:

> umsonst = um nichts (bzw. in D: für nichts)

Daraus schließe ich nun, dass die in Österreich noch heute gebräuchliche und vorherrschende Form »das gibt es **um** [Betrag]« jene Form ist, die in der Vergangenheit auch in Deutschland üblich war.

Daraus ergibt sich dann diese Frage:

Wann und warum wurde in Deutschland die Phrase »das gibt es **um** [Betrag]« durch die heute dort gängige Form »das gibt es **für** [Betrag]« ersetzt?

Ein alternativer Ansatz müsste davon ausgehen, dass es in Deutschland statt »*umsonst*« das Wort »*fürsonst*« (mhd: *vür sus*) gegeben habe, doch kann ich dafür keine Anhaltspunkte finden.

Comment: Um Dich komplett zu verwirren: es gibt in der (de-DE) Umgangssprache auch den Ausdruck »für umme«, offenbar eine Verkürzung von »für umsonst«.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Einen genauen Zeitpunkt kann ich Dir nicht sagen, aber es lohnt ein Blick in [Grimms Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GF12033#XGF12033):

> 4c) *als erwiderung, gegenleistung, vergeltung, ausgleichung, die betrift: mhd.*
>   ...
>   *ist aber der den werth bezeichnende ausdruck von für abhängig, so hat dieses den sinn: in dem werthe betragend, in dem werthe der beträgt.* herr Richard ist so gütig gewesen und hat mir versprochen, die neue andrienne seiner frau liebste mir für geld und gute worte zu lassen. Gellert *lustsp.* 429. er hat das haus für zehntausend thaler gekauft. er erstand das buch für zwanzig silbergroschen.
>   *so schon mhd. und mitteld.*: daʒ wir virkauft hân Bërcholde Feiʒten ... eine halbe marg gëldis ûf unseme hûse unde hovestad biz an dën burnen und dër burne dar zû gên dëm wëge, fur iv marg pennege. ... *die gewöhnliche praep. aber ist mhd. umbe, mitteld. umme, unser nhd. um, das wir ja auch noch hier in demselben sinne wie für gebrauchen.*

Ich verstehe das so, dass zu Grimms Zeiten "um" noch als die "gewöhnliche" (gebräuchlichere? weniger gehobene?) Variante galt, die Version mit "für" aber schon in Gebrauch war und sich sogar bis ins Mittelhochdeutsche zurückverfolgen lässt. Irgendwann danach (und diesen Zeitpunkt muss ich schuldig bleiben) hat "für" dann "um" in Deutschland komplett verdrängt.

Comment: In Österreich hört und sieht man `um 10 Euro` immer noch, meistens in der Werbung.

Comment: @Wernfried: Nicht nur in der Werbung. Ich kannte bis vor 2 Tagen die deutsche Version »*für 10 Euro*« überhaupt nicht. (Bin 1965 in Graz geboren und 1997 nach Wien gezogen)