# Adapt to Austrian grammar and spelling as Swiss expat

Tags: austrian, swiss-standard-german

#### German Version:

Ich komme aus der Schweiz und habe daher das "Schweizer Hochdeutsch", oder "Schweizer Standarddeutsch", gelernt. Ich werde bald für ein paar Jahre an einer Universität in Österreich arbeiten. Sollte ich dann versuchen, wenn ich deutsche Texte (vor allem E-Mails) schreibe, die lokale "Österreichische Standarddeutsche" Rechtschreibung und Grammatik zu verwenden oder weiterhin die Rechtschreibung/Grammatik die ich gelernt habe anzuwenden?

Ich fürchte, dass wenn ich mich nicht anpasse und z.B. E-Mails mit "Freundliche Grü**ss**e" statt "Freundliche Grü**ß**e" beende, der Empfänger entweder denkt dass ich die Deutsche Rechtschreibung nicht beherrsche oder, falls er weiss woher ich komme, dass ich durch die Verwendung der Schweizer Rechtschreibung in Österreich arrogant bin.

Auf der anderen Seite gibt es viele kleine Unterschiede und ich werde sehr wahrscheinlich nicht alle lernen. Also werden meine E-Mails immer noch "Fehler" drin haben. Daher wäre es möglicherweise sinnvoller alles mit der Schweizer Rechtschreibung/Grammatik zu schreiben damit alles konsistent ist. Ebenfalls ist das Schreiben von ß auf einer Schweizer Laptop Tastatur sehr mühsam und gewisse Formulierungen (E.g. AT "Ich kaufe ein Brot **um** 5 Euro" vs. CH "Ich kaufe ein Brot **für** 5 Euro") klingen für mich sehr falsch. Ich plane früher oder später (in 2-5 Jahren) zurück in die Schweiz zu ziehen wo solche Ausdrücke für Verwunderung sorgen würden.

Dies wird vor allem den E-Mail-Verkehr mit Studenten, Arbeitskollegen und staatlichen Ämtern betreffen. Andere Texte sind entweder informell (wo mir Rechtschreibung/Grammatik egal ist) oder Englisch.

Was soll ich machen? Oder kümmert das die wenigsten und kann ich daher machen was ich will?

#### English version:

I'm from Switzerland and as such know the "Swiss standard German" grammar and spelling. I just finished my studies and am moving to Austria for a few years for a job at an university. In this situation, when writing german texts (mostly emails) should I should adapt to the local "Austrian standard German" grammar/spelling or stay by the grammar I learned?

The main reasons to adapt to it seem that when writing an email and ending it with "Freundliche Grü**ss**e" instead of the Austrian "Freundliche Grü**ß**e" i might either appear to have no clue about German spelling or, if they know where I'm from, that i'm arrogant by using Swiss spelling in Austria.

On the other hand, there are many small differences and I will most likely never learn them all in time. So even if I try to write Austrian German I'il still make a lot of "mistakes". Therefore for the sake of consistency it might make more sense to just keep to the grammar/spelling I learned. Also, typing a "ß" is PITA on a Swiss laptop keyboard (I copy & pasted it from google) and some Austrian German expressions just sound plain wrong (E.g. AT "Ich kaufe ein Brot **um** 5 Euro" vs. CH "Ich kaufe ein Brot **für** 5 Euro"). I plan to move sooner or later (2-5 years) back to Switzerland where accidental use of such formulations would look *very* silly.

This will probably mostly affect emails with students, co-workers and state agencies. Other texts will mostly likely either be very informal (I don't care about grammar in those) or in English.

So what should I do? Or will most people just not care and I can do whatever I want?

Comment: "Ich kaufe ein Brot um 5 Euro" Wie sagt man das in der Schweiz? Grüße/Grüsse ist Rechtschreibung und nicht Grammatik. Die minimalen Unterschiede in der Grammatik fallen vermutlich gar nicht auf. Was die Rechtschreibung betrifft: Es gibt genug Österreicher die sich selbst nicht gut auszukennen scheinen (oder überhaupt die alte Rechtschreibung verwenden). Du würdest also sicher nicht als stur oder eingebildet auffallen, höchstens als jemand, der die aktuelle Rechtschreibung nicht beherrscht. Aber das ist nur meine Meinung, die Frage lässt sich nicht wirklich beantworten.

Comment: Wenn deine Muttersprache Deutsch ist (was ich aufgrund deines Namens und deines Wohnortes vermute), dann solltest du hier in diesem Deutsch-Forum deine Fragen bitte auf Deutsch stellen, denn ca. 98% aller hier gegebenen Antworten werden von Menschen gegeben, deren Muttersprache ebenfalls Deutsch ist. Wenn du aber auf Englisch fragst, entsteht die perverse Situation, dass sich Menschen mit Deutsch als Muttersprache in einer Fremdsprache über ihre Muttersprache unterhalten. Das sollte man tunlichst vermeiden.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Danke vielmals, ich wollte ursprünglich die Frage auch auf Deutsch stellen, doch als ich sah dass alle anderen neuen Fragen auf der Startseite auf Englisch sind schloss ich daraus dass es gebräuchlich sei hier Englisch zu schreiben. Werde mich an eine Übersetzung machen!

Comment: Gibt es denn überhaupt eine eigene "Schweizer Grammatik", die sich von der deutschen und österreichischen unterscheidet? Es gibt Unterschiede in der Rechtschreibung, es gibt Begriffe, die nur in einem Land existieren - aber die eigentliche Grammatik ist doch gleich?

Comment: @IQV: Ich kenne mich mit Schweizer Deutsch nicht so gut aus, aber im österreichischen Deutsch haben schon die Zeitformen der Vergangenheit aus gutem Grund andere Namen als im deutschen Deutsch. *»Mitvergangenheit«* und *»Vergangenheit«* werden im österreichischen Deutsch zwar gleich gebildet, aber ganz anders verwendet als *»Nachvergangenheit«* und *»Vorgegenwart«* im deutschen Deutsch. Auch viele andere Konstruktionen sind unterschiedlich, z.B. die schon erwähnten Präpositionen (in D kauft man etwas *für* einen gewissen Betrag, in Österreich aber *um*).

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger: nur zur Klarstellung: [Du musst nicht auf Deutsch schreiben, aber Du darfst](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-language-should-the-questions-be-written-in). **Fragen auf Englisch** sind überhaupt nicht "pervers", sie **sind völlig OK**, weil dann auch Nicht-Muttersprachler mitlesen können (NB wir sind immer noch eine amerikanische Seite). Es hängt aber ein wenig von der Zielgruppe ab, die Du erreichen willst. Fragen, die im ganzen SE-Netz vorgestellt werden (HNQ), sind meist auf Englisch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: wenn Du es als "pervers" empfindest, wenn wir uns mit Rücksicht auf die vielen englischssprachigen Benutzer auf Englisch unterhalten, und wenn Du Deutsch hier zur Pflichtsprache machen möchtest, musst Du dazu ein Votum auf [Meta] einholen. Solange Du das nicht hast, solltest Du in der Wortwahl Deiner Kommentare bitte ein wenig Zurückhaltung üben. Danke.

Comment: Ich glaube, man muss hier zwei Sachen auseinanderhalten - Gesprochene und geschriebene Sprache - Gesprochen ist es sicher so, dass jeder Muttersprachler akzeptiert, dass es verschiedene Regionen gibt, in denen die deutsche Sprache leicht variiert, und alleine schon deine Schweizerische Aussprache wird das erklären - Bei geschriebener Sprache ist das etwas anders.

Comment: Nur ein, zwei Randbemerkungen: In meinem E-Mailprogramm kann ich wählen zw. de_DE, de_AT, de_CH und weiteren. Um fünf Euro wird es aber wohl nicht vorschlagen - nur die ß-Geschichte zu lösen helfen. @Takkat: Mein Wörterbuch definiert 'pervers' als 'nicht der Fortpflanzung dienend'. Den Terminus finde ich nicht so völlig unpassend. :) Während des Studiums hatte ich einen guten Freund aus Linz (OÖ) in Berlin und dieser hat sich weitgehend angepasst, aber sich eigentlich nie korrigiert, wenn er ein ö. Idiom benutzt hat. Sporadisch hat er die Frage thematisiert und s. selten absichtlich abgegrenzt

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger: Merke: Email = glasartiger Überzug auf Metall (z.B. Geschirr oder Schmuck). E-Mail = elektronische Post.

Comment: @Takkat: Das Wort *»pervers«* bedeutet *»verkehrt, widersinnig«*. Wenn sich Menschen mit der Muttersprache Deutsch in einem Deutschforum über die deutsche Sprache unterhalten, empfinde ich es durchaus als *verkehrt* und *widersinnig*, diese Kommunikation in einer anderen Sprache als Deutsch zu führen, und ich scheue mich auch nicht, diese Widersinnigkeit zum Thema zu machen und beim Namen zu nennen.

Comment: Ich denke Du musst von Fall zu Fall unterscheiden, wie diplomatisch Du sein willst und wie angepasst. Tastaturen kann man per Software umstellen und sich auch für 2 Jahre eine neue kaufen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Da scheint ein grundlegendes Missverständnis vorzuliegen: Wir führen hier keine Unterhaltungen, daher ist dein Vergleich unpassend. Was hier passiert, ist eher eine Podiumsdiskussion, bei der es auch nichtmuttersprachliche Zuhörer gibt. Daher ist es durchaus sinnvoll, diese Diskussion in einer Sprache zu führen, die denen einen Zugang erlaubt. Und der Meta-Beschluss lautet, soweit ich weiss, immer noch, dass die verwendete Sprache freigestellt sein soll.

Comment: @tofro: Was hilft es einem Japaner, einem Perser oder einem Russen, der Deutsch lernen will, wenn hier alles auf Englisch steht? Die Leute besuchen diese Seite nicht, um Englisch zu lernen, sondern um Deutsch zu lernen. Englisch ist hier erlaubt, weil es viele Leute gibt, die diese Sprache sprechen. Aber nicht alle, die hierherkommen können Englisch. Aber alle, die hierherkommen, wollen Deutsch lernen. Die Sprache, die hier alle vereint ist nicht Englisch, sondern Deutsch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Funnily the only allowed language on Chinese SE is English. No pure Chinese allowed in questions and answers! I find it an abomination.

Comment: @JIXiang: German SE ≠ Chinese SE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich antworte auf Deutsch, weil ich davon ausgehe, dass das deine Muttersprache ist.

### ss - ß

Die Entscheidung, ob das scharfe S durch ein Doppel-S ersetzt werden darf, hat nichts mit Grammatik zu tun. Das gehört ganz eindeutig in das Gebiet der Rechtschreibung, und hier ist die Regelung ganz klar: Das generelle Ersetzen ist nur im schweizerischen Deutsch erlaubt. Schweizerisches (Hoch-)Deutsch ist eine der drei Standardvarietäten der deutschen Sprache, die beiden anderen sind deutsches Deutsch und österreichisches Deutsch.

Wenn du deutsches Deutsch oder österreichisches Deutsch verwendest, darfst du das scharfe S nicht durch SS ersetzen. Diese Regel ist recht simpel.

Die eigentliche Frage ist also: Welche Sprache sollst du verwenden, wenn du in Österreich bist?

Ich vergleiche deine Situation mal mit der eines deutschen Immigranten:

Der typische deutsche Immigrant schert sich einen Dreck um das österreichische Deutsch. Aber nicht aus Bosheit oder sonst einer Absicht, sondern weil die meisten von ihnen nicht mal wissen, dass das Deutsch, das in Österreich verwendet wird, ein anderes ist als bei ihnen daheim. (Viele von ihnen machen sogar den Fehler, die Einheimischen bei der Verwendung ihrer eigenen Muttersprache korrigieren zu wollen, was meist nicht gut ankommt.)

Wir Österreicher sind es daher durchaus gewohnt, wenn man mit uns in unserem eigenen Land in einer Ausprägung der deutschen Sprache spricht, die hier nicht heimisch ist.

Daher empfehle ich dir, es den Deutschen gleich zu tun: Komm einfach her, und sprich und schreib wie du es daheim gelernt hast. Wir verstehen dich schon (solange du kein Schwizerdütsch sprichst, aber ich rede hier ja ohnehin nicht von Dialekten).

Wenn du lange genug in Österreich bist, wirst du die notwendigen Vokabel, die andere Aussprache einiger Wörter und die etwas andere Grammatik ohnehin schnell lernen. Denn so groß sind die Unterschiede zwischen den einzelnen Varietäten zum Glück ja nicht. Wenn wir Berliner und Hamburger verstehen, kommen wir mit Bernern auch klar.

### um 5 Euro

Wie schon gesagt: Wir verstehen dich auch, wenn du statt *»**um** 5 Euro«* *»**für** 5 Euro«* sagst ([das wird hier genauer behandelt](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/20577/1487)), denn das hören wir hier auch ständig von den Deutschen die bei uns leben. Solange du zum Topfen nicht *Quark* sagst, nehmen wir es dir auch nicht übel.

Answer (score 4):

German is not my mother tongue, so I can't really answer about specifics of things like *ß* vs. *ss* and *um 5 Euro* vs. *für 5 Euro*. Nonetheless, I see the underlying situation as being not so different from that of an American working in the UK, or a Brit working in the USA etc.

In any case, I would suggest heeding the advice of the proverb, *When in Rome, do as the Romans.* If (as a Brit) I were working in the US with American colleagues, I would do my best, especially in any formal or semi-formal written communication, to stick to American English spelling conventions & vocabulary, and avoid any peculiarly British expressions etc.

Mistakes are inevitable, but that's how we learn. At the very least I would suggest that it shows a positive attitude to your students and colleagues, when you make the effort to adapt your (formal) language usage to the customs of your host country. Even if that means "unlearning" what you have spent many years learning.

**Side note on typing ß on a keyboard which doesn’t have a specific key for it** (incorporating comments by Christian Geiselmann, LangLangC and Hubert Schölnast)

On Microsoft Windows, the key combination Alt+0223 using the numeric keypad (if you have one) works. On a Mac, Alt+s may work, although it depends on the language of the keyboard.

Another option may be to tell your operating system to offer the keyboard layouts of the language in question, and assign keyboard shortcuts to them.

Comment: The Alt+0223 code is useful of course only when you have a full keyboard. On most laptops you don't, and switching over to numpad mode and back is too complicated. - I recommend doing the obvious: tell your operating system to offer also the keyboard layouts of the language in question, and assign keyboard shortcuts to them. E.g. I press Alt+Shift+0 for the German keyboard (which is fine for English, too), Alt+Shift+9 for Bulgarian (classical typewriter) layout, and similar other keys for Turkish and Russian. All those have letters that are not available on any other keybord layout.

Comment: Also a good answer, +1. I have a laptop, and at least in ubuntu (my primary system) rebinding some unused key combination to ß isn't going to be a problem. But i'm also using OSX where stuff like that is usually a bit messy, so changing the whole keyboard language seems to be a good option.

Comment: Ironisch ist es aber, dass ich diese Antwort auf Englisch geschrieben habe.

Comment: Alt+0223 works only if you OS is from microsoft. Ich you use Linux or a product from Apple, it doesn't work.

Comment: @LangLangC: When I type Alt+s on my iMac, I get a comma. The code depends on the language of the keyboard. It is not universal.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I'd say the more sensible way is just to switch the keyboard layout to German (AT) or German (DE) or something like that. You don't need to "assign keyboard shortcuts". Even though your keyboard doesn't have "ß" written on it, you can type it where it's supposed to appear, e.g. "-" key on an originally English keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

Wie wäre es, du machst folgendes: Gar nichts!

Du kannst meines Erachtens einfach weiter deine bewährten Schweizer Schreibweisen und Ausdrücke verwenden. Wer es liest und wem es überhaupt auffällt, der denkt sich eben: "Ah, ein Schweizer! Das trifft man selten!"

Ich persönlich würde es sogar interessant finden, einen Brief mit leichten Schweizer Eigenheiten zu bekommen.

Nun kann ich natürlich nicht für das österreichische Lesepublikum sprechen. Ich bin aufgewachsen in Süddeutschland - Schweizer und Österreichischer Rundfunk eingeschlossen; der präzisere Wetterbericht kam immer vom Schweizer Fernsehen. Das heißt, gewisse Schweizer Eigenheiten sind mir vertrauter als jemandem weiter nördlich. Aber Österreicher sollten eigentlich kein Problem damit haben, oder?